# Slickgrid group row is not seen

Tags: slickgrid

I am trying to implement grouping in slickgrid based on the following example.

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example-grouping.html

The only difference being I do not have any filter, so I don't call `dataview.setFilter()`

Below is my grouping code.

```
@columns =
        [
          {id: "fname", name: "First Name", field: "firstName", formatter: @formatFname, sortable: true, width: @setWidth(30)}
          {id: "lastName", name: "Last Name", field: "lastName", sortable: true, width: @setWidth(30)}
          {id: "email", name: "Email ID", field: "email", formatter: @formatEmail, onClick: @launchEmail, sortable: true, width: @setWidth(60)}
]

groupItemMetadataProvider = new Slick.Data.GroupItemMetadataProvider

    dataViewOptions = {
            groupItemMetadataProvider: groupItemMetadataProvider
            inlineFilters: true
    }

    @dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView(dataViewOptions)

    dataView.beginUpdate()
    dataView.setGrouping({
          getter: 'lastName'
          formatter: (g) ->
            console.log("g is : ",g)
            'Duration:  ' + g.value + ' items'
          aggregators: []
          aggregateCollapsed: false
          lazyTotalsCalculation: true
    });
    dataView.setItems(data)
    dataView.endUpdate()
```

I am even able to see my groups with proper title set to each group.

[image: My groups from debugging]

[image: One of my groups object]

[image: But I am not getting any slick group row displayed in my grid.]

[image: Here is the html after grouping. No slick group rows are seen here]

But I am not seeing any group rows in my slick grid.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using ES6 features that I'm not familiar with, but the code looks suspicious to me, eg

```
dataView.setGrouping({
      getter: 'lastName'
      formatter: (g) ->
        console.log("g is : ",g)
        'Duration:  ' + g.value + ' items'
      aggregators: []
      aggregateCollapsed: false
      lazyTotalsCalculation: true
});
```

There are no commas between the elements of this object definition.
Also, the arrow function does not look correctly formed to me. Since there are two statements, it should be contained in braces and have a `return` keyword.

Comment: I am using coffee script. Thats why the syntax changes.

Comment: Ah, OK. Not familiar with that. Have you tried putting the ```dataView.setItems(data)``` command *before* the ```setGrouping```?